# Is it ever useful for only one thread to use memory_order_seq_cst?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, atomic, memory-barriers, stdatomic

In a multithreaded program, do you ever get any guarantees from `memory_order_seq_cst` that you wouldn't also get from a weaker ordering, if you only have one thread that uses it? Example:

```
#include <stdatomic.h>

extern atomic_int x, y;

void doSomething(void);

void thread1(void) {
    atomic_store_explicit(&x, 1, memory_order_seq_cst);
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
    if(atomic_load_explicit(&y, memory_order_seq_cst)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}

void thread2(void) {
    atomic_store_explicit(&y, 1, memory_order_release);
    atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acq_rel);
    if(atomic_load_explicit(&x, memory_order_acquire)) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

If `thread1` and `thread2` are running in parallel, is it guaranteed that exactly one will always call `doSomething`?

Comment: In practice, it should be easy to construct cases where a seq_cst operation (especially a plain store) compiles with a StoreLoad barrier that would otherwise be present.  And for other threads to observe the difference.  But C compilers make code that's safe for any other hypothetical thread, so you can get stronger ordering than strictly required for the actual threads that exist in a program.  (e.g. in many ISAs, the cost of StoreLoad ordering is placed on the stores, so acquire loads can use the same asm as SC loads.  https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~pes20/cpp/cpp0xmappings.html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe no, it doesn't give any extra guarantees if only one thread uses it.

The only difference between seq-cst and acqure/release is the existence of the global seq-cst operation order.

Other threads can't observe nor influence this order without performing seq-cst operations. This order thus [copies the *"sequenced-before"*](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.17.3p6) order of the single thread that uses seq-cst operations, since nothing else constrains it.